# React Navigation - correct way to stop interval

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm fetching data every 5s in interval. I would want to stop fetching this data once I transition to another screen (using React Navigation).

What is the best way to do this. I'm using useFocusEffect and helper variable as you can see in example below.

Is this the best practice or is there a better way to achieve it?

```
useEffect(() => {
    const id = setInterval(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, isPlaying ? 5000 : null);

    return () => clearInterval(id);
}, []);

useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
        setIsPlaying(true);

        return () => setIsPlaying(false);
    }, [])
);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a more common way to handle memory leaks and have it trigger when playing changes, I did something similar for a stopwatch app that looked like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    let id;
    if (isPlaying) {
      id = setInterval(() => {
        fetchData()
      }, 5000);
    }

    return () => {
      clearInterval(id);
    };
  }, [isPlaying]);
```

Comment: Yes, but I was asking specifically in context of navigation.navigate(). Sorry if I didn't express it clearly enough. Your interval will still be running if you navigate away (not back). Right?

Comment: @user3554626I think the useFocusEffect hook from the core navigation library is what you're looking for in that case, you can change the playing state in it upon mounting and unmounting just like a regular hook